# VSCode: Python, Unexpected argument alerts

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have recently moved from PyCharm to VSCode for Python programming, and am missing the PyCharm functionality to alert you of unexpected named arguments and method calls.

This helps me identify when I am using an argument from the wrong class, or have mistyped an argument.

Does similar functionality exist for VSCode?

Screenshot of how the functionality looks in PyCharm below

[image: Unresolved reference]

[image: Unexpected argument]

Comment: I'm a pycharm-er and suffer absence of this functionality too. Did not find this in vscode

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for the [Linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) and [Autocomplete and IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing) of python in the VSCode.

In briefly, you need to install the extension of `Python` and `Pylance` and add these in the settings.json file:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
"python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
```

Comment: @Rasmus Lehmann Have you solved the problem? if this is helpful, could you accept this answer? thanks, and have a good day : )

Comment: Thank you for the answer Steven! But no, this did unfortunately not provide the functionality I was looking for. I have updated the question with a screenshot of how the functionality looks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the python extension in VSCode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kermit! 
I have already downloaded the extension called "Python" - however many more exist. Which one are you referring to? "Python for VSCode", "Python Extension Pack", "Python Preview" or an entirely different one?